# Using PV nodeaffinity with pod node affinity

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

Suppose I have a persistent volume PV1 with a given NodeAffinity.

Now there is a pod Pod1 which also has the same NodeAffinity. Then I should be able to mount PV1 on Pod1.

But suppose I have another persistent volume PV2 which does not have any node affinity values defined. Then in that case can I still mount PV2 on Pod1? Or do I need another pod with no nodeaffinity and mount PV2 on that pod?

Comment: Let me know if the provided info helped you in overcoming the issue, if not share me the details to troubleshoot the issue further

Answer (score 0):

For most of the volumes you don’t need to set `PV node affinity`, except for [local volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local).

Usually in a  `PV` we will specify node affinity to define which nodes this volume can be accessed from, regardless of pod node affinity.

So in your case you are telling that `pv1` should mount or schedule the pod in the node that matches that node selector. whereas in the `pv2` it can be mounted in any node including the pod with node affinity.

Now you can use `PV2` on pod1 without creating a new pod, here the PV can be used by any Pod on node it is scheduled on, but you have specified the node affinity on the pod spec, so pod will schedule on that without checking the node affinity in PV. So you can mount `PV2 on pod1`, let me know if you are facing any issue while mounting.